# Informatica workflow is dropping records from Oracle view

Tags: oracle, view, informatica, informatica-powercenter

I build a straight 1-1 mapping on Informatica 10.5 with Oracle view as a source and Oracle Table as target. The mapping has View -> SQ -> Exp Tran -> Target. Informatica workflow when triggered is dropping few records from Oracle view. I ran the same SQ query from session log on database it is reading correct records.

What could be the scenarios that Informatica is not recognizing few records from Oracle view (Source) ?

Please provide suggestions to fix this. In my initial analysis I found out that it is not reading few rows from source which has col : start_date > '01/01/2020' in 'mm/dd/yyyy hh24:mi:ss' format.

Answer (score 0):

If your have any format issue, informatica will reject the records to loaded into the table. Please check your session log, you will get the column and value on which you are having format issues. Also check your mapping if you have mapped any string column to numeric/ date datatype.